# How to make a torrent from another torrent.?

Tags: bittorrent

Most of the torrent out there consist of various files or dir under it. Many times it happens that I want a single file or want to share a single file from it rather than sharing all of them. I want to know; suppose a torrent file having x, y, and z content files under it,. i want to share only file x. How can I make a sub-torrent from a torrent *WITHOUT DOWNLOADING IT???*...
For a practical ex, there are various sites that allows direct download links. I want just one file from the torrent to download, but I cant even process it as its over a gb. However the file is under 1 GB.
I hope someone can give an answer or show a direction. Anything related to content is welcomed. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You mean this? : http://i.imgur.com/2MsgyL3.jpg (utorrent screenshot)

Comment: Thanks for attention. Now the question is how can u make a .torrent/magnet file for only daft punk Homework without downloading it

Comment: @Abhioxic - I do not particularly care about what you are downloading, but what you want is against the spirit of the BitTorrent protocol. In principle, please do not just leach, but give back to the community.

Comment: @MarkLopez why? Anybody can download just the file of their choice and decide to seed it or not. How is it different from creating a separate torrent just for that file? Downloads will be more unbalanced, but more downloads of that file means more seeds of that file. I don't understand why you consider it leeching.

Comment: @gronostaj Because you are not downloading the whole torrent. Check out the differences between Structured and Unstructured p2p networks. The efficiency of the BitTorrent network and the DHT decrease when peers do not have all the pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a new torrent by keeping only some files, follow these steps:

1. Download [BEncode Editor](https://sites.google.com/site/ultimasites/bencode-editor).
2. Make a backup of the original `.torrent` file.
3. Open the file using BEncode Editor, and expand the `info` node.
4. Remove all items items in the `files` subnode, except those you want to preserve.
5. Save the new torrent.

**Note** When editing `.torrent` files, any changes to the `info` structure will change the the torrent hash. This means you won't be able to download or upload files from/to peers having the original torrent.

Comment: You forgot to answer the important (emphasized) part of the question. To create a functional torrent you (or someone else) must seed it and to seed it **you must have its content** (the files).